# Insert date to database in c#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I found lot of questions regarding this matter and I tried everything but couldn't succeed yet.

I need to pass date to my SQL Server database. my code is as follows:

```
public bool CreatePatient()
{
    IDbConnection connection = database.CreateOpenConnection();
    IDbTransaction transaction = database.BeginTransaction(connection);

    try
    {
        GenerateRegNo();

        SQL_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO TblPatientRegistration(RegistrationNo, HospitalID, NIC, AdmitDate, BHTNo, WardNo) 
                         VALUES(@RegNo, @HospiatlNo, @NIC, @Admitdate, @BHTNo, @WardNo)";

        IDbCommand com = database.CreateCommandTransaction(SQL_STATEMENT, connection, transaction);

        com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@RegNo", PatientRegistration.RegistrationNo));
        com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@HospiatlNo", PatientRegistration.HospitalID));
        com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@NIC", PatientRegistration.NIC));

        com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@Admitdate", PatientRegistration.AdmitDate));
        com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@BHTNo", PatientRegistration.BHTNo));
        com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@WardNo", PatientRegistration.WardNo));

        if (com.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            string updStatement = "Update TblControl set RegNo=RegNo+1";
            IDbCommand com2 = database.CreateCommandTransaction(updStatement, connection, transaction);
            com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            transaction.Commit();
        return true;
        }
        else
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            return false;
        }
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        transaction.Rollback();
        return false;
     }
}
```

**What I have tried:**

As mentioned above [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/468096/1395178)

```
  com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@Admitdate", PatientRegistration.AdmitDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));
```

and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7176687/1395178)

```
com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@Admitdate", "'"+PatientRegistration.AdmitDate+"'"));
```

then I tried with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9223572/1395178)

```
 String UrDate = PatientRegistration.AdmitDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
 System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo dateInfo = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
 dateInfo.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
 DateTime validDate = Convert.ToDateTime(UrDate, dateInfo);

 com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@Admitdate", validDate));
```

These methods throw this exception :

> *Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date*

Value I received `PatientRegistration.AdmitDate` from is : `{2/25/2013 12:00:00 AM}`

I tried with these all methods but couldn't able to save it. please help me to figure out the problem in here.

Thanks...

**EDIT :**

My database schema :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TblPatientRegistration](
    [RegistrationNo] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [HospitalID] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [NIC] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [AdmitDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [BHTNo] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [WardNo] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ReleaseDate] [date] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TblPatientRegistration_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RegistrationNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**This question may already have an answer here (close vote):** -->i tried with the answer that have suggested in there (see option 2), but it seems not working with my problem

**Answer:**
after several investigation i found this problem occurs due to my mistake in database.

i have not passed value to ReleaseDate field and it set to `default value` in database. that default value is the one says incompatible with date. So that is the cause for this problem.
any how I'm able to pass my value as mentioned by Ashok kumar

Comment: post the table schema

Comment: What is the data type of your column?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead- i tried AdmitDate as Date and DateTime both types. but it give same exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date/The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176596/operand-type-clash-int-is-incompatible-with-date-the-insert-statement-conflicte)

Comment: Try 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.

Comment: @mbeckish even that it gives same error.

Comment: Please provide your class for your `database` object.  I think most people are assuming you're using the standard ADO framework method named CreateParameter, but I can see that it is not.

Comment: @Sybeus i tried to introduce transaction lock in my code. do you think that can be the cause for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code at @Admitdate line only.

```
public bool CreatePatient()
{
    IDbConnection connection = database.CreateOpenConnection();
    IDbTransaction transaction = database.BeginTransaction(connection);

    try
    {
    GenerateRegNo();

    SQL_STATEMENT = "INSERT INTO TblPatientRegistration(RegistrationNo, HospitalID, NIC, AdmitDate, BHTNo, WardNo) 
                     VALUES(@RegNo, @HospiatlNo, @NIC, @Admitdate, @BHTNo, @WardNo)";

    IDbCommand com = database.CreateCommandTransaction(SQL_STATEMENT, connection, transaction);

    com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@RegNo", PatientRegistration.RegistrationNo));
    com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@HospiatlNo", PatientRegistration.HospitalID));
    com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@NIC", PatientRegistration.NIC));

        String admitDate = txtAdmitDate.Text;
        DateTime parsedAdmitDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(admitDate, "d/M/y", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedAdmitDate))
            PatientRegistration.AdmitDate = parsedAdmitDate;

    //com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@Admitdate", PatientRegistration.AdmitDate));
    com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@BHTNo", PatientRegistration.BHTNo));
    com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@WardNo", PatientRegistration.WardNo));

    if (com.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
        string updStatement = "Update TblControl set RegNo=RegNo+1";
        IDbCommand com2 = database.CreateCommandTransaction(updStatement, connection, transaction);
        com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        return false;
    }
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
    transaction.Rollback();
    return false;
 }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: even though it still gives me same error. i tried to introduce transaction lock in my customize database class code. do you think that can be the cause for this problem? pdated my question with my database class coding

Comment: I understood from your code and message that you are facing the problem with datatype mismatch. (Am I right?) As far my knowledge concernsed I won't think that the introduction of transaction lock on customized database class causes this problem, but I am not sure. Is it possible for you to check by removing trasaction lock on your customize database and try again?

Comment: i have another class called person and in there also have date field called DOB. so i introduce my transaction lock to that class. :) it works properly on there. but not in here. :(

Comment: thanx ur help. this is happen due to my stupid work. i have not passed value to ReleaseDate field and it set to default value. so that is the cause for this problem

Answer (score 1):

The data type of your Database table column is `Date`, can you try `DateTime` or a `datetime2`.

And dont enclose the Date variable in quotes:

```
com.Parameters.Add(database.CreateParameter("@Admitdate",PatientRegistration.AdmitDate))
```

Comment: i tried with DateTime previously and it also did not allow me to save. so thats why i changged to date - [AdmitDate] [date] NOT NULL,

Comment: I found the same error here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7176687/495455, I cant be sure but am quietly confident that answer is the solution.

Comment: yah from there i got that solution. but i didn't work for me. i'll change my db and try it.

Comment: i tried that one and even though it throws same exception - `Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date`

Answer (score 1):

`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourDateTimeVariable", dateTimeObject);` ????

Comment: tried not worked ...  i tried to introduce transaction lock in my customize database class code. do you think that can be the cause for this problem? updated my question with my database class coding

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", DateTime.Now);
```